# TDAmeritrade API Authentication Error: Failed to resolve API Key variable request.header.un

Tags: php, api, oauth

I'm having difficulty obtaining an access token from the token endpoint using PHP (https://developer.tdameritrade.com/authentication/apis/post/token-0)

Particularly, I'm getting the following error:

> { "error":"Failed to resolve API Key variable request.header.un" }

My request, using PHP, is:

```
  $url = 'https://api.tdameritrade.com/v1/oauth2/token';

  $client_id = $customer_key ;

   $redirect_uri = $redirect_URL;
  $myvars = array("grant_type" => "authorization_code"
                  , "access_type" => "offline"
                  , "client_id" => $client_id
                   , "redirect_uri" => $redirect_URL
                  , "code" => "$code");

  $ch = curl_init( $url );
  curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
  curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $myvars);
  curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
  curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
  curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 1);
  curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
    'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=utf-8'

          ));

  $response = curl_exec( $ch );
  echo "<br>token = '$response'\n";

}
```

Thanks!

Comment: Im reading the reddit page for this API and apparently the API isn't all that good or reliable. Having said that, here are instructions on how to get a 90 day access token https://developer.tdameritrade.com/content/simple-auth-local-apps and here's the reddit page https://www.reddit.com/r/algotrading/comments/914q22/successful_access_to_td_ameritrade_api/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OK, I finally got a working PHP script that authenticates into the TD API and obtains account information. I'd like to share it with everyone because I couldn't figure out how to get it working after almost three months. A special thanks to Ninet3 for helping me out. You can direct questions to his Fiverr profile (https://www.fiverr.com/ninety3)

```
$redirect_URL = 'https://YourURL.com';
$redirect_URL = urlencode($redirect_URL);
$customer_key = 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX';
$account_number = '1234567890';

$url_endpoint = 'https://auth.tdameritrade.com/auth?response_type=code&redirect_uri='.$redirect_URL. '&client_id='.$customer_key.'%40AMER.OAUTHAP';

if(NULL === @$_GET['code']) {
    header("Location: $url_endpoint");//open TD website to get tokens
}


if($_GET['code'] !== '') {
    $code = $_GET['code'];

    $code = urlencode($code);
    if($code){
        $curl = curl_init();

        curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
            CURLOPT_URL => 'https://api.tdameritrade.com/v1/oauth2/token',
            CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
            CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
            CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 0, CURLOPT_HEADER  => false,
            CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => true,
            CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => 'POST',
            CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array('Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
            ),
            CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => 'grant_type=authorization_code&refresh_token=&access_type=offline&code='.$code.'&client_id='.$customer_key.'&redirect_uri='.$redirect_URL,
        ));

        $response = curl_exec($curl);

        curl_close($curl);
        $response = (json_decode($response, true));
                echo '<pre>';
                echo 'access_token: <br>';
                print_r($response );


 //Get account information      
        if(@$response['access_token'] !== null){
            $acc = $account_number;
            $curl = curl_init();

            curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
                CURLOPT_URL => 'https://api.tdameritrade.com/v1/accounts/'.$acc,
                CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
                CURLOPT_ENCODING => "",
                CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
                CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 0,
                CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => true,
                CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
                CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => 'GET',
                CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
                    'Authorization: Bearer '.$response['access_token'],
                ),
            ));

            $response = curl_exec($curl);

            curl_close($curl);
            echo '<pre>'.$response;

        }else{
            echo 'unable to get access token'; exit;
        }
    }
    else{
        echo 'No Code Found'; exit;
    }
}else{
    echo 'No Code Found'; exit;
}
```

You'll need to store the token in a database and refresh to get a new one after the time expires.

Comment: Thanks for posting this, I totally understand it. Except, I get confused with $code, access_token and refresh token? So when my access_token expires (usually in 30 mins), Do I have to go thur the whole $url_endpoint / code process again? The TD documentation isn't really clear on the refresh_token and I have tired to use it but then expires for no reason. 

Also on your $url_endpoint, doesn't that require you to sign in via a user interface or are you already signed in another browser tab?

Comment: Man, thank you so much for this. I have literally been trying for a month to get this to work and this is the first working code sample I've found. I can't figure out how this is any different from the manual CURL command that they themselves generated for me, which failed every time with "invalid grant", but it is. I filled in my details and it worked without modification. Sweet!

Answer (score 0):

I found this page when I got the exact same error message. I finally figured it out after quite a few tries and stepping away a few times. The biggest change from what you've posted is that when you use the header:
`"Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded"`
which TD wants for this API, you need to make the `$myvars` array into a string like the following:

```
$myvars = "grant_type=authorization_code&access_type=offline&code=".$code."&client_id=".$client_id."&redirect_uri=".urlencode($redirect_uri);
```

The other note here is the urlencode function to help url encode the string. It talks about that in the 'Notes' section of this page:

https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! As you can see, I've been struggling with this for a while.

I tried you suggested modification and now I receive the following error: 
"error" : "invalid_grant"

Any suggestions?

I also get this error when I try to use TD's sandbox: https://developer.tdameritrade.com/authentication/apis/post/token-0

Comment: Oh, sorry, double check that your `$code` variable is URL encoded too. I forgot about that. If you're going by the guide at https://developer.tdameritrade.com/content/simple-auth-local-apps they talk about needing to URL decode the code parameter you get back in the URL to use in the TD form on that page that you just linked to, but you need to have it encoded in the string when you make your API call. It's more work when you do it manually (the same way I did to get it going the first time).

Comment: Yes, I have:
$code = urldecode( $code );
$code = str_replace( " ", "+", $code);   
I'm still getting the same error. If I private message you my code, can you run it? Perhaps there is an issue with my TD account. They had earlier closed my account because it was dormant. I reopened a new one. So I'm not sure if it's something on their end or not.

Comment: Ok, that works. One other thought I have is that you might have to go back and get a new auth code from step 1 of the Simple Auth for Local Apps page, then try the TD token form/your script again after these PHP code changes? I just tried to run that TD token web form with the last code I have, but I get that 'invalid_grant' error, too. However, my PHP code works just fine to pull from multiple APIs with the valid refresh token I have and then on to getting an access token.

Comment: I think my issue is with the headers. Right now I have: curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER,array
('Authorization: Bearer $code'
));   And I get the error "Source variable : request.header.Authorization for basic authentication decode policy is not valid"